# COUNTSIFS multiplying by a value for multiplying shifts by shift length in roster

Tags: excel

I have an excel table where it has shifts down the left side and days on top.  [As can be seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xSxR.png)

To calculate how many times a staff member has shifts that day I use this forumula.
`=COUNTIFS(D:D,"*"&$L8&"*",D:D, "<>*#*")`
Which coutns the amount of times a staff member in this example L8 would have their name appear in the roster, I also use a # to signfy to not count the shift.

As seen in [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xSxR.png) I also have a Length column next to the shift name which specifies how long the shift is. What I want to do is convert the activity column to whenever it finds a name Im looking for add up the time for that shift so I can see a table of how long people are working for.

If needed an example of the worksheet can be found here: https://ufile.io/81rv8

Comment: Sounds like a case of sumifs, instead of countifs, or am I getting something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Enter this formula in `M8` cell

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C$73,D$3:D$73,"*"&$L8&"*",D$3:D$73,"<>"&"*#*")
```

Comment: That appears to be working however the # symbol where I can add a `#` to not track doesnt work, i.e. it still counts cells which have a # in it.

Comment: The formula was working fine. I guess you are adding # symbol along with the activity code. I have updated the formula in my answer. If you are adding the # symbol in some other columns please let me know.